# Android Manipulate Images on Canvas - working with touch, move, zoom - in/out, scale

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint, android-photoview

I am working on Photography app like this :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photo.editor.collage.maker.photoblender&hl=en

I have to implement functionality like this : 
[image]

I have 2 functionalities with this view...

1)  with splash background

[image]
[image]
[image]

2) with blurred background

[image]
[image]
[image]

Both are using 2 shapes....
Now as you are using path to draw shape....i wants to draw image bitmap shape like above.

I have more shapes like below (All having 2 images as above):

3)

[image]
[image]

I wants to replace this portion of code you are using :

```
private void createPath() {
            path.reset();
            path.moveTo(114, 156);
            float[] points = {68, 138, 19, 136, 21, 87, 8, 39, 56, 26, 97, -2, 123, 40, 163, 71, 131, 109};
            for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
                path.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);
            }
            path.close();
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, 160, 160), clip, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            path.transform(m);
            transformedPath.set(path);
        }
```

i did above functionality by adding shape as path, but when i am trying to use shapes as bitmap i didn't get complete result.... here is my code for view.

```
class MotionImageView extends View implements MatrixGestureDetector.OnMatrixChangeListener {
    private final Bitmap shapeMaskBitmap;
    private final Bitmap shapeShadowBitmap;
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint monoPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint borderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Bitmap bitmap, blur;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix pathMatrix = new Matrix();
//    Path path = new Path();
//    Path transformedPath = new Path();
    MatrixGestureDetector detector;
    RectF clip = new RectF();

    public MotionImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.e("~~~~", "1111");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.model);
        blur = blur(context, bitmap, 8);
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0.25f);
        monoPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setColor(0xccffffff);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        borderPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        detector = new MatrixGestureDetector(pathMatrix, this);

        shapeMaskBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shape_mask);
        shapeShadowBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shape_shadow);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Shader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        matrix.mapRect(clip, src);
//        createPath();
    }

    /*private void createPath() {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(114, 156);
        float[] points = {68, 138, 19, 136, 21, 87, 8, 39, 56, 26, 97, -2, 123, 40, 163, 71, 131, 109};
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
            path.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);
        }
        path.close();
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, 160, 160), clip, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        path.transform(m);
        transformedPath.set(path);
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(blur, matrix, monoPaint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(clip);
//        canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(shapeMaskBitmap, pathMatrix, paint);
        canvas.restore();
//        canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, borderPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(shapeShadowBitmap, pathMatrix, borderPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(Matrix matrix) {
//        path.transform(matrix, transformedPath);
        pathMatrix.set(matrix);
        invalidate();
    }

    Bitmap blur(Context ctx, Bitmap src, float radius) {
        Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(src.getConfig(), true);

        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(ctx);
        Allocation blurInput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, src);
        Allocation blurOutput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        blur.setInput(blurInput);
        blur.setRadius(radius);
        blur.forEach(blurOutput);

        blurOutput.copyTo(bitmap);
        renderScript.destroy();
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

My output was like this :

[image]

Comment: yes i need it, if you have it.

Comment: so instead of `canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, paint);` and `canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, borderPaint);` call `drawBitmap` twice - the second time with porter duff `Mode.SRC_IN` - see many solutions on how to mask one image with the another, like [this](https://badoo.com/techblog/blog/2016/10/17/masking-bitmaps/) for example

Comment: or you can use `BitmapShader` but the mask image has to be in `ALPHA_8` format - see `Bitmap#extractAlpha()` method

Comment: i said:`ALPHA_8` is it `ALPHA_8`? did you read a link i posted above?

Comment: hey bro...i was just trying what you said, i wants to do it first myself, i don't wants to bother you bro... now as i didn't get it send me your code if possible. well thanks for it bro.

Comment: i have read all your above comments and tried it my self.. thanks for your time and share me how to do it with bitmaps instead of paths.

Comment: so what is the format of your mask `Bitmap`? is it `ALPHA_8`?

Comment: YES, it is alpha_8 image

Comment: i mean `shapeMaskBitmap`, not `shapeShadowBitmap` - post the code how are you checking that `shapeMaskBitmap` has `ALPHA_8` format

Comment: i wants code urgent give me if you have. i have just above two bitmaps 1 for mask and 1 for shadow, use that images and give me result if you have. i didn't get the concept of ALPHA_8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you are trying to do with `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` and `BlurMaskFilter` will not work, if you want effect like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

you have to use `BitmapShader` and `ScriptIntrinsicBlur`, see this sample custom `View`:

```
class V extends View implements MatrixGestureDetector.OnMatrixChangeListener {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint monoPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint borderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Bitmap bitmap, blur;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix pathMatrix = new Matrix();
    Path path = new Path();
    Path transformedPath = new Path();
    MatrixGestureDetector detector;
    RectF clip = new RectF();

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.forest);
        blur = blur(context, bitmap, 8);
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0.25f);
        monoPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setColor(0xccffffff);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        detector = new MatrixGestureDetector(pathMatrix, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Shader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        matrix.mapRect(clip, src);
        createPath();
    }

    private void createPath() {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(114, 156);
        float[] points = {68, 138, 19, 136, 21, 87, 8, 39, 56, 26, 97, -2, 123, 40, 163, 71, 131, 109};
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2) {
            path.lineTo(points[i], points[i + 1]);
        }
        path.close();
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, 160, 160), clip, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        path.transform(m);
        transformedPath.set(path);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(blur, matrix, monoPaint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipRect(clip);
        canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, paint);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.drawPath(transformedPath, borderPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(Matrix matrix) {
        path.transform(matrix, transformedPath);
        invalidate();
    }

    Bitmap blur(Context ctx, Bitmap src, float radius) {
        Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(src.getConfig(), true);

        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(ctx);
        Allocation blurInput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, src);
        Allocation blurOutput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        blur.setInput(blurInput);
        blur.setRadius(radius);
        blur.forEach(blurOutput);

        blurOutput.copyTo(bitmap);
        renderScript.destroy();
        return bitmap;
    }
}

class MatrixGestureDetector {
    private static final String TAG = "MatrixGestureDetector";

    interface OnMatrixChangeListener {
        void onChange(Matrix matrix);
    }

    private int ptpIdx = 0;
    private Matrix mTempMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private OnMatrixChangeListener mListener;
    private float[] mSrc = new float[4];
    private float[] mDst = new float[4];
    private int mCount;

    public MatrixGestureDetector(Matrix matrix, MatrixGestureDetector.OnMatrixChangeListener listener) {
        if (matrix == null) throw new RuntimeException("Matrix cannot be null");
        if (listener == null) throw new RuntimeException("OnMatrixChangeListener cannot be null");
        mMatrix = matrix;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getPointerCount() > 2) {
            return;
        }

        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        int index = event.getActionIndex();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                int idx = index * 2;
                mSrc[idx] = event.getX(index);
                mSrc[idx + 1] = event.getY(index);
                mCount++;
                ptpIdx = 0;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                for (int i = 0; i < mCount; i++) {
                    idx = ptpIdx + i * 2;
                    mDst[idx] = event.getX(i);
                    mDst[idx + 1] = event.getY(i);
                }
                mTempMatrix.setPolyToPoly(mSrc, ptpIdx, mDst, ptpIdx, mCount);
                mMatrix.postConcat(mTempMatrix);
                mListener.onChange(mMatrix);
                System.arraycopy(mDst, 0, mSrc, 0, mDst.length);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                if (event.getPointerId(index) == 0) ptpIdx = 2;
                mCount--;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: when using `Bitmap`s instead of `Path`s the code is shorter by couple of lines:

```
class V extends View implements MatrixGestureDetector.OnMatrixChangeListener {
    Paint monoPaint = new Paint();
    Paint srcInPaint = new Paint();
    Bitmap mask, maskShadow, bitmap, blur;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix maskMatrix = new Matrix();
    MatrixGestureDetector detector;
    RectF clip = new RectF();

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.mask).extractAlpha();
        maskShadow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.mask_shadow);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.forest);
        blur = blur(context, bitmap, 8);
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0.25f);
        monoPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        srcInPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        detector = new MatrixGestureDetector(maskMatrix, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        matrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        matrix.mapRect(dst, src);

        src.set(0, 0, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight());
        maskMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        setupClip();
    }

    private void setupClip() {
        clip.set(0, 0, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight());
        maskMatrix.mapRect(clip);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(blur, matrix, monoPaint);
        drawMask(canvas);
    }

    private void drawMask(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipRect(clip);
        canvas.saveLayer(clip, null, 0);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mask, maskMatrix, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, srcInPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(maskShadow, maskMatrix, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(Matrix matrix) {
        setupClip();
        invalidate();
    }

    Bitmap blur(Context ctx, Bitmap src, float radius) {
        Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(src.getConfig(), true);

        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(ctx);
        Allocation blurInput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, src);
        Allocation blurOutput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        blur.setInput(blurInput);
        blur.setRadius(radius);
        blur.forEach(blurOutput);

        blurOutput.copyTo(bitmap);
        renderScript.destroy();
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

Comment: hey pskink, while saving final image, why the shape is not clear, i've tried a lot on it, can you help me out on this issue.

Comment: look at your result image the shape border is has no clear edges

Comment: its not my image: its yours: https://i.imgur.com/a80S9aL.png - you made the shadow blurred, not i

Comment: i had figured out the issue, it's just supportsRtl issue on some devices. anyways thanks